# ImportError: No module named pymssql error when run from batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, pymssql

I have a simple .py file that queries a DB server with pymssql that works as required.
I am trying to schedule a task to run the script but it fails
When I call the .py file from a batch file I get the below error:

```
import pymssql
```

ImportError: No module named pymssql

Any ideas why this is failing when run from a batch file ?

Python 2.7.6
Running on Windows 2008 R2

Comment: If it works when you try it standalone and fails when you schedule the taks, it's probably a matter of `pymssql` not being in the patth (different environments, maybe even different versions of Python?).

Comment: C:\python27 is in the path. is there anything else I should add ?

Comment: Just for fun, try to log somewhere the contents of `sys.path` when running the scheduled process, and compare it to the one you get when the script works.

Comment: Do I need to import pymssql in a Python file other than my script ?

Comment: If your script is just one file, no, of course. Anyway, the error is generated by an `import` statement that won't find the module, somehow

Comment: But seriously. Make your script to do `import sys` and print out the contents of `sys.path`. Compare the contents of the path in both cases (working vs. non working) and see if there are any differences

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it turned out that the Python.exe I used when testing the script was in C:\Python27(32 bit) and not C:\Program Files\Python27 (64bit)
I needed to specify the correct exe and it worked.
thanks to those who contributed

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues however I was running on Raspberry Pi. Had trouble running them from etc/rc.local and it kept showing me the error.

**What I did**

1. Created **print_path.py** in the directory of the python script you wanted to run and write the following:

   import sys

   print(sys.path)
2. Go to terminal
   Make use of this line which i took from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file):

   sudo python3 [path_of_file]/[nameoffile].py > [path_of_file]/output1.txt
3. Go to terminal

   sudo nano etc/rc.local
   Place the following into rc.local:

   sudo python3 [path_of_file]/[nameoffile].py > [path_of_file]/output2.txt &

** Take note of the Ampersand

**Compare the two outputs**
You should be able to find the path that differs.
Then copy the missing path.

**Put into python script(that you want to run on boot)**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
```

It should be working because it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

try adding the full path of the module (like this "C:\myfolder\mymodule.py") to the %path% variable within the batch file and then executing it

PS: 
Set %path% = %path%+"C:\myfolder\mymodule.py"
should look something like this

Comment: Tried and I got the same error. here's my batch file:

Set %path% = %path%"D:\Apps\Scripts\myscript.py"
"C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe" D:\Apps\Scripts\myscript.py

Comment: Ok, So I have tried starting from scratch with a new batch file and ensuring the full path was included in the batch file. I have also updated the PATH enviornment varible but no luck. any other ideas ?

Comment: Why dont you add a job or a trigger to run your script?

Comment: I originally created a scheduled task to call the script but I kept getting error 0x1. I then called the script from a batch file to try and capture the error being thrown

Comment: Do I need to import pymssql in a Python file other than my script ?